# Bancos de dados relacionais e objeto-relacionais

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Quais são as diferenças entre bancos de dados relacionais e bancos de dados objeto-relacionais?

Comment: Este artigo apresenta uma visão sobre o assunto.
https://www.devmedia.com.br/bancos-de-dados-relacionais/20401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em essência o banco de dados objeto relacional é um banco de dados relacional, portanto trabalha com dados tabulares relacionados no modelo físico para formar objetos. A diferença se dá no modelo lógico que tenta dar uma aparência de objetos completos e interagir melhor com linguagens de programação que incentivam o uso da orientação a objeto. Então todo modelo usa classes, heranças, criação de tipos e até alguma forma mais sofisticada de criação de comportamento.

Até onde eu sei todas tentativas de fazer isso funcionar fracassaram (curiosamente outras tentativas de fazer outros modelos tiveram sucesso mesmo tendo mais problemas que esse modelo, mas nossa indústria é assim, depende das forças de mercado mais do que é bom ou ruim do ponto de vista de engenharia). Alguns produtos ficaram com resquícios disto, um exemplo é o PostgreSQL. Algumas ideias acabaram sendo adotadas no bancos de dados relacionais.